# Unity Character Controller and Colider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem, 
I try put my character on the floor with the box collider and my character controler and script (look in scrennshot)but he always cross the groundes...
Can you help me ? sorry for my bad english ..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVUwj.png)

Comment: floor have collider or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your player a rigidbody2D.  You need a rigidbody2D to physically interact with the collider.  Otherwise you would need to detect 'Triggers' and manually code in stops to movement when your player enters the trigger of a wall.   A Rigidbody2d will detect collision (in different modes that you can select) with colliders and engage the physics engine, if you will.